# My User LanguageLocaleKey gets overridden

Tags: administration, language, locale

I am trying to change my LanguageLocaleKey from "es" to "en_US". I go to Workbench update the record, get the confirmation screen and when I look at the field, it changed back to "es". What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the encoding of your file.

If your file encodeing isn't correct then salesforece will have trouble matching it to the picklist.